# Debugging statfs?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, unix, hardware

I am using statfs to retrieve the total space available on my hard drive. It returns the correct values most of the time, but sometimes it just returns an error for no apparent reason. I want to find out why it generates an error at seemingly random times.

Is there a way I could check why it's generating an error? If I print `strerror(errno)` I simply get the message "No such file or directory". This tells me what the problem is, but not whats causing it. I don't see any reason why it's able successfully to find the directory at a certain moment but then not be able to locate it the next moment. Is there any way I could check what's causing this? I doubt if it's a problem with my code because if that was the case, if wouldn't ever return the correct data.

I am passing in '/'as the directory. I am on OS X Snowleopard using Xcode 3.2.6 using Objective-C/C

- How could I locate the problem that's causing it to not find the
  path?
- What are some general reasons that would cause it to be able to find the drive at one moment and not the next?

Code used to retrieve info:

```
    if (statfs(&path, &storageStats))
    {               
        NSLog(@"Total storage stats retrieval failed with errno: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        totalAmount = storageStats.f_blocks * storageStats.f_bsize;
        NSLog(@"Storage: %f\n", totalAmount);
        return self;
    }
```

I get the "Total storage stats retrieveal failed ..." and the errno message is "No such file or directory"

Comment: How are you determining that `statfs` "returns an error"? Show us a code snippet.

Comment: @R.. I added the code into my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to statfs is a char *.  Since you are passing &path, that would imply that path is a char.  If that is the case, then you are passing a null terminated string only sometimes.  (If path is '/' and the next byte happens to be '\0', then the call will work.  If the memory after path is not '\0', then you are passing a very strange path to statfs.)  You probably meant to do:

```
char *path = "/";
statfs( path, ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to correct sizing of the path string variable:
Call `pathconf()` to get the value of `PATH_MAX`.  Then use that PATH_MAX value to declare your string variable for your path.

PATH_MAX +1 guarantees you won't find a path longer than your string.